# select multiple values in drillthrough report by kind of like expression

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

I have a report ("main report") from where I can reach a drillthrough report that has a multivalue parameter "Product". The parameter has labels and values like follows:

Product A             [Product].[Product]&[1]&[1]
Product B             [Product].[Product]&[1]&[2]
Product C            [Product].[Product]&[2]&[1]

Coming from the main report, in the drillthrough report I would like to select all parameters whose values start with

```
[Product].[Product]&[1]
```

Currently, in the main report I load a dataset with all products of this type, fill them into a multivalue parameter and hand the value of this parameter over to the drillthrough report. My question is, is there an easier way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use only one dataset with all products in the main report and to filter them:

```
=Filter(Parameters!Product.Value, "[Product].[Product].&[1]", true)
```

The filter function will look for the expression inside the multiple product parameters and return all starting with this expression.